# Is there a tool to migrate from ASP MVC 4 to PHP MVC?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created one project in ASP MVC4 and SQL Server, and now I have to convert it to PHP MVC.

Is this possible? Is there any tool, or any idea how to do that?

Comment: You have to do it by hand, for sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

This conversion will take a while. The ASP code will have to be converted by hand. But you can keep your SQL server code. You'll just have to connect PHP to your database server manually. Read up on connecting PHP to a database.